# JQuery selectors not working on elements modified at runtime?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have no doubt this is something really dumb, but I haven't written code in like 2 years.

I'm able to "deselect" only the items that were "selected" when the page loaded, but I cannot deselect the ones I select at runtime.  I also cannot "select" the one I am able to deselect. Assuming it's the same issue.  I thought I remembered `on` replacing `live` which addressed exactly this, but apparently I'm wrong.

```js
$('.tile').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
$('.tile.selected').on('click', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.tile {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tile.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tile"></div><div class="tile selected"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div>
```

Comment: Since `$('.tile.selected')` is evaluated at runtime, it will find only the elements that match the `.tile.selected` query at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting it for the document:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tile.selected', () => { /* your code */ });
```

which will set for the `.tile.selected` that is in the document in all times, not only when the page is first loaded

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.tile').on('click', function () {
    if ($('.tile').hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

```css
.tile {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tile"></div><div class="tile selected"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div>
```